# Call an Enity Framework method from Revit add-in causes NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, revit-api, revit, notsupportedexception

I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model using Entity Framework code-first in a `RevitAddin` project.

```
public static  class ElevationDao
{
    public static int GetId(int length)
    {
        var db = new DbContext();

        var obj = db.Elevations.Where(x => x.Value == length);

        if (obj.Count() == 0) 
           throw new Exception();

        return obj.First().ID;
    }
}
```

And I call this function in `Execute` method of Revit command:

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class Class1 : IExternalCommand
{
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        int id = ElevationDao.GetId(3300);
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
}
```

When I execute this command, Revit throws a `NotSupportException` and automatically shuts down its session.

Can anyone explain this and give me a hint? Thank you.

PS: It only happens on my laptop, On my company's computer, it works fine.

[image: NotSupportException when using Entity Framework in Revit Addin]

Comment: May I know if you already added the ref of the library to the solution? Take a look on your 'Reference' in solution explorer.

Comment: Dear MatrixTai, I already added libray to my project (using Nugget), work fine in a console project.

Comment: .NET is suspicious about DLLs that are loaded from remote (network) locations, rather than the local machine.  Is there anything that you're doing with this DLL or any referenced DLLs that would be making it load referenced DLLs from a network drive?

Comment: I synchoronized the project on GitHub. I've already fixed it by reinstalled Revit 2018 :). May be there were errors when using Revit. Anyway, thank you.